# EPPlus 4.1.1 Error CS0103 cuando se crea ExcelPackage

Tags: c#, excel

Estoy obteniendo este error cuando se crea ExcelPackage y no encuentro por qué.

> Error CS0103
>
> No se puede encontrar el valor solicitado 'baseline'."

```
var info = new FileInfo(RutaArchivo);

using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(info)) 
// El pck inicia una excepcion

// pck.Workbook.Worksheets  'pck.Workbook.Worksheets' inició una excepción de tipo 'System.NullReferenceException'{System.NullReferenceException}
{

// Exception.Message = No se puede encontrar el valor solicitado 'baseline'."

ExcelWorksheet worksheet_Excel = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First(); 
// pck.Workbook.Worksheets error CS0103: El nombre 'pck' no existe en el contexto actual    
if (worksheet_Excel != null)
{
}
}
```

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**, explica qué estás haciendo y qué esperas obtener. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78).